# What is an efficient way to cross-compare two different data pairs in Excel to spot differences?

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, office365, comparison

### Summary

I am looking to compare two data sets within Excel, and produce an output depending on which has changed, and what to.

### More info

I hold two databases, which are updated independently. I cross compare these databases monthly, to see which database(s) have changed, and who holds the most accurate data. The other database is then amended to reflect the correct value. I am trying to automate the process of deciding which database needs to be updated. I'm comparing not just data change, but data change over time.

### Example

On month 1, database 1 contains the value "Foo". Database 2 also contains the value "Foo". On month 2, database 1 now contains the value "Bar", but database 2 still contains the value "Foo". I can ascertain that because database 1 holds a different value, but last month they held the same value, database 1 has been updated, and database 2 should be updated to reflect this.

### Table Example

| Data1 Month1 | Data2 Month1 | Data1 Month2 | Data2 Month2 | Database to update | Reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Foo | Foo | Foo | Foo | None | All match |
| Apple | Apple | Orange | Apple | Data2 | Data1 has new data when they did match previously. Data2 needs to be updated with the new info. |
| Cat | Dog | Dog | Dog | None | They mismatched previously, but both databases now match. |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | Data1 | Data2 has new data when they did match previously. Data1 needs to be updated with the new info. |
| AAA | BBB | AAA | BBB | *CHECK* | Both databases should match, but you cannot ascertain which should be updated. |
| ABC | ABC | DEF | GHI | *CHECK* | Both databases changed, but you cannot tell if Data1 or Data2 is correct as they were updated at the same time. |

### Current logic

Currently, I'm trying to get this to work using multiple nested `=IF` statements, combined with some `=AND` and `=NOT` statements. Essentially, an example part of the statement would be (database 1, month 1 = DB1M1, etc.): `=IF(AND(DB1M1=DB2M1,DB2M1=DB2M2),"None",IF(AND(DB1M1=DB2M1,DB1M1=DB2M2,NOT(DB2M1=DB1M2)),"Data2",IF(ETC,ETC,ETC)`.

I've had some success with this, but due to the length of the statement, it is very messy and I'm struggling to make it work, as it becomes unreadable for me trying to calculate the possible outcomes in just `=IF` clauses. I also have no doubt it's incredibly inefficient, and I'd like to make it more efficient, especially considering the size of the database is around 10,000 lines.

### Final Notes / Info

I'd appreciate any help with getting this to work. I'm keen to learn, so any tips and advice are always welcomed.

I'm using MSO 365, version 2202 (I cannot update beyond this). This will be run in the Desktop version of Excel. I would prefer this is done exclusively using formulas, but I am open to using Visual Basic if it would be otherwise impossible or incredibly inefficient. Thanks!

Comment: is there any typo in the Excel version? Please clarify which version. It looks you are coming from the future, :-)

Comment: @DavidLeal - The version number is correct, taken from Excel itself. What should the version number be? 
https://i.imgur.com/9NqjuWF.png

Comment: I see, yes it is confusing Microsoft Version, maybe this is some internal number tracking. In your question you used the tag office365 so we are good. I was wondering based on the version number you provided what excel functions we can use. Here is a [List of excel functions organized by Excel version](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/functions/updates-365-new-functions.htm)

Answer (score 0):

In previous similar scenarios, it sounds me familiar using *bitwise operations* or *binary numbers*. The main idea behind a binary number is that each digit can act as flag indicating if certain property is present or not.

The goal is to identify if two databases (`DB1`, `DB2`) are on sync based on a given value over two periods (`M1`, `M2`). If one database is out of sync we would like to know which action to carry out to have it on sync with respect to the other database. Similarly we would like to know when both databases are out of sync at the end of the period.

Here is the Excel solution in cell `M2`, then extend down the formula:

```
=LET(dec, 
 BIN2DEC(IF(B2=C2,0,1)&IF(D2=E2,0,1)&IF(B2=D2,0,1)&IF(C2=E2,0,1)), 
 DBsOnSync, ISNUMBER(FIND(dec, "0;10;3;9;11")), 
 DBsOutOfSync, ISNUMBER(FIND(dec, "7;12;13;14;15")),
 IFERROR(IFS(dec=5,"Update DB1", dec=6,"Update DB2", DBsOnSync=TRUE,
 "DBs on Sync", DBsOutOfSync=TRUE, "DBs out of Sync"), "Case not defined")
)
```

[image: sample excel file]

The input table tries to consider all possible combinations, so we can build the logic. The **highlighted columns are not really necessary, it is just for illustrative or testing purpose**. In red combinations already defined previously so it is no really necessary to take into account.

### Explanation

We build a binary number based on the following conditions for each binary digit. This is just an intermediate result to convert it to a decimal number via `BIN2DEC` and determine the case for each possible value.

```
BIN2DEC(IF(B2=C2,0,1)&IF(D2=E2,0,1)&IF(B2=D2,0,1)&IF(C2=E2,0,1))
```

We have four conditions, so we build a binary number of length `4`, where each digit represent a flag condition (`0`-equal, `1`-not equal).

We build the binary number that will be the input for `BIN2DEC` via concatenation of the logical conditions we are looking for. Each `IF` condition represents a binary digit from left to right:

- `IF(B2=C2,0,1)` check for `DB1`, `DB2` are consistent in `M1` (intermediate calculation shown in column **M1**).
- `IF(D2=E2,0,1)` check for `DB1`, `DB2` are consistent in `M2` (intermediate calculation shown in column **M2**).
- `IF(B2=D2,0,1)` `DB1` keeps consistency over time (intermediate calculation shown in column **DB1**).
- `IF(C2=E2,0,1)` `DB2` keeps consistency over time (intermediate calculation shown in column **DB2**).

Converting the binary number to decimal, we can identify each case, assigning a set of decimal numbers. The following decimal number or set of decimal numbers represent each case:

| dec | Scenario |
| --- | --- |
| `0,10,3,9,11` | `DBs on Sync` |
| `5` | `Update DB1` |
| `6` | `Update DB2` |
| `7,12,13,14,15` | `DBs out of sync` |

We use `IFS` and `FIND` to identify each case based on `dec` value. We use `FIND` to find `dec` in the string that represents the set of possible numbers for each case. We use `ISNUMBER` to check whether the number was found or not. We include as last resource, for testing purpose, if some case was not defined yet, it returns `Case not defined`.

### Notes

Columns **F:I** give a hint about maximum number of possible combinations. We have four columns, with only two possible values: `Sync`, `NotSync`. Which represents `2*2*2*2=16` combinations, which represents the maximum possible binary numbers of size `4` we can have (we have four conditions).

As you can see from the screenshot we have less numbers of unique combinations (`12`). The reason is because the way we build the binary numbers they have dependencies, so some combination are impossible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I really appreciate the insight. It does make sense, and does work as required, with one slight exception. If a 3rd value is added, it seems to produce an incorrect answer. For example: a,a,b,c says to update DB2, but the correct output should be to say DBs out of sync. I can get around this by wrapping the formula in an =IF statement to check the number of unique values, and to change it to "DBs out of sync" in the value count is above 2, but I was wondering if it would be possible to work this into your logic using the bitwise operations. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: @Wisp that is correct, this case was not considered. I updated the answer to consider this case. I have to add an additional condition and therefore to work with a binary number of four digits instead of three. I hope it helps to adapt this idea to your real problem. My answer pretends to serve as a guideline on how to handle a situation like this. In my opinion scenarios with a lot of possible combinations instead of building complex `IF-ELSE` conditions it is better to approach it through binary conditions represented as a binary number.